# Count(id) in MySQL into a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have the SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT yearoffiling, COUNT( id )
FROM files
GROUP BY yearoffiling
LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

How do I put the values from `COUNT(id)` inside a string?

Thank you.

Comment: Strongly recommend that you add underscores to your words: `year_of_filing`. Otherwise your databases are going to be a pain to debug / review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy, just to add to yours i think you may need the AS attribute to do the modifaction

```
$query = "SELECT yearoffiling, COUNT( id ) AS total FROM files GROUP BY yearoffiling LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Comment: Please select one of the answers on this page that you consider to be the best solution using the check mark beside said answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "SELECT yearoffiling, COUNT( id ) total FROM files GROUP BY yearoffiling LIMIT 0 , 30";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($ary = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo $ary['total'];

}
```

This is how I would do it "old school". I recommend using prepared statements and PDO these days. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would add the AS attribute to the COUNT(id) part of the query just to ensure mysql labels the column.

Comment: AS is not required with mysql, but probably good practice, as it keeps the query similar to other databases where it's required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the [convert() or cast()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) functions to do this.

```
SELECT cast(COUNT(id) as char), ....
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies...Thanks. Duh, I am attempting to write SQL in the middle of a Java session. Happens all the time. Once I coded all day in VB then tried to deliver a lecture in Java in the night. Only when a student stopped me to ask what I was writing did I realize that all my comments were '.

Comment: @Vincent: Happens to all of us

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question that the OP intended to ask.  He's almost certainly wondering how to get the value of the "count column" into a PHP variable.  He has no interest in the internal mysql datatype in play.

Answer (score 2):

There's two steps to this:

1. Define a column alias for the `COUNT(id)`
2. Optional: Change datatype MySQL uses for the column to minimize datatype conversion issues

### Defining a Column Alias

A column alias is always defined *after* the column declaration, including computed columns like `COUNT(id)` in your example.  As you've noticed, they're required for computed columns in order to reference the value in other places.  You can use the `AS` notation, or simply declare the alias within single quotes.  Examples:

```
COUNT(id) AS count_id
COUNT(id) 'count_id'
```

Both are valid syntax, but mind that if you use MySQL keywords you'll have to use backticks (`) to escape the value for the query to execute.

You can name an alias anything you like, but it really should be informational.  If unsure, use the hallway test - randomly ask people in the hallway if it makes sense.

### Changing the Datatype

This is required when you deal with any programming that does not perform implicit type casting, which would require you to get the column value (in this case an integer) and convert it to a string (or any other desired data type - decimal, float, etc.).  You can use either of the [MySQL CAST or CONVERT functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) - they are synonyms of one another.  Examples:

```
CAST(COUNT(id) AS VARCHAR(4))
CONVERT(COUNT(id), VARCHAR(4))
```

Be aware that this is occurring with the realm of MySQL, so you can only CAST/CONVERT to [MySQL datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html).